# Custom product page's style for printing

Tags: plugins, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, screen-layout

I m using woocommerce for product listing on site but i changed default single product page's layout with elementor. Now when i'm trying to print it changes layout on preview. Product's image size takes full width & many column changes it's place but i want to print this as it appears on browser.
Help me plzz!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably print styles defined in your stylesheets. Look for `@media print` in your css, and write your own rules as such:

```
@media print {
  img {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

etc...